# Web API, IQueryable, OData and HttpResponseMessage as return-type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, httpresponse, iqueryable

During the past days I have seen some great examples of how to use the HttpResponseMessage-type as a return-type for the Web API actions.. which then makes Unit-testing alot easier since it makes it possible to "fake" the whole HttpMessage that you would get in any normal case where you would need to actually do a real request again the actions using WebClient or such in your unittest and also need to run two instances of Visual studio..

Anyway.. lets say that I want to use this approach with the HttpResponseMessage.. but I also want to use the new IQueryable-OData-thingy.. would that even be possible.. since I guess I then would query a bunch of HttpResponseMessages.. which at least as far as I know, there only supposed to be one off...

So the HttpResponseMessage approach would sort of "break" the whole idea with the IQueryable and OData.. or am I right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Queryable would work if response.Content is an ObjectContent and contains an `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`. If you are creating your response using `Request.CreateResponse` helpers, querying would work. Also, as an FYI, `Task<IQueryable<T>>` would work too.

Comment: Way too little information here, I just tried what you said and since the OData's EdmModelBuilder in WebApi.Config.cs expects IQueryable or IEnumerable it throws an exception to have HttpResponseMessage as return type on ODataController actions. Or can you provide more details about this?

Answer (score 1):

I manage to have a web api returning an HttpResponseMessage and still be able to use OData just by setting the `[EnableQuery]` attribute:

```
[EnableQuery]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(MyModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)422, "Unprocessable Entity");

    //your-code-here

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myEnumerable);
}
```